# Unable to run applications with GUI through x11 forwarding

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

I have Ubuntu server 14.04 on which i want to run applications with GUI. I have Xauth installed and i have edited the files `ssh_config` and `sshd_config` to allow X11 forwarding. On my PC I have Windows 7 OS and I am using Cygwin to connect to the server. I am using this command to connect: `ssh -X -i private-key.pem ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx`

But when I try to run some application with GUI, for example Leafpad, I get error: `leafpad: Cannot open display`

Also, if I run the command `xrandr` I get the same error: `Can't open display`

Any idea why I am getting these error messages?

Comment: Windows does not have an X11 server by default. Have you installed one?

Comment: I have it installed on Cygwin.

Comment: Does running `xhost +` on cygwin help?

Comment: If i run `xhost +` i get this: `xhost:  unable to open display ""`

Comment: At this point I suspect it's more a windows/cygwin problem than an Ubuntu one. Try asking on superuser.sx

Comment: Well, i have Ubuntu server installed locally on virtual machine and if i connect from it to the remote Ubuntu server using ssh and x11 forwarding and try to run apps with gui i am getting the same errors that i am getting with Cygwin. And i even installed full desktop environment on the remote server. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

With your server properly configured, and with X11 server installed on your Windows.

You might need to run `export DISPLAY=YOUR_IP:0` on it after connected to the server. The "YOUR_IP" should be change into the IP address of your Windows.

Or, you can try to run `startxwin` in you Cygwin shell before connect to the server, which will brings up a xterm window for graphical stuff. It will complete the DIPSLAY setting for you automatically, and you should be able to run graphical applications.

You can test the result with `xlogo` command.

Reference:

- http://www.arsc.edu/arsc/knowledge-base/ssh-and-x11-forwarding-us/index.xml
- http://cypresslin.web.fc2.com/Memo/M-ENG-SSH.html

Comment: I installed x11 server on Cygwin and i started the server with the command `startxwin` but when i try to open gui app like leafpad i get this message:

`Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyleafpad: Cannot open display:` 

Also if i run `xlogo` command i get this error: `Error: Can't open display: xx.xx.xx.xx:0` xx.xx.xx.xx is my external IP address.

Comment: Do you have your server with "X11Forwarding" set to yes in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file?